# How can I write this in haml? (rails app)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

```
<a href="/">
  <i class="material-icons">file_download</i>
  Export to CSV
</a>
```

I am using a material_icon gem. "file_download" is a download icon in a material icon. I want it to be like a button with the download icon and the text "Export to CSV" next to it.

Comment: https://html2haml.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be something like:

```
= link_to foo_path do
  %i.material-icons file_download
  Export to CSV
```